# I want to fire a javascript code when a adobe air application is being un-installed

Tags: jquery, air, adobe

I have built a application using javascript and html to run on Adobe AIR. I want to know when the application gets un-installed, i.e, when the application get uninstalled i want to fire a event that the program is being uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in AIR. There is no "uninstall" event.